# how do i know id previous element

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click

how do i know **id** checkbox when you click on **`<span class="CheckBox">`**?

Code:

```
<div id="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="demo" name="status" class="status" style="display: none; ">
<span class="CheckBox">
<span class="CBContent">Block</span>
<span class="CBPart"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

Start code Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.CheckBox').on("click", function(){
```

what should be further actions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jquery [**prev()**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8NeV/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", '.CheckBox', function() {
        previousId = $(this).prev().attr('id');
        alert(previousId);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.CheckBox').on("click", function(){
  var $checkbox = $(this).prev();
  var $id = $checkbox.attr("id");
});
```